# How to get `MediumLevelILVar` type variable reference In Binary ninja with Python api?

Tags: reverse-engineering

I tried to use binary ninja to analysis obfuscated binary function. I want to use python api for binary ninja to get variable **var_3290** reference like this:
[image]
I used the api `get_var_uses` which only can be received as `variable.Variable` type,but `var_3290` is `MediumLevelILVar`,called this api will got error!

```
get_var_uses
    var_data = var.to_BNVariable()
AttributeError: 'MediumLevelILVar' object has no attribute 'to_BNVariable'
```

How can i do like binary ninja cross reference behavior? thanks.

To get the `var_x3290` variable's cross reference like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `get_var_uses`  and `get_var_definitions` with `MediumLevelILVar` type data's `src` method like this:

```
    var=None
    if isinstance(state_var,MediumLevelILVar):
        var = state_var.src
    else:
        var = state_var
```

state_var as a MediumLevelILVar type data.